# Suddenly lost files on Lenovo Y540, Mageia 7 without warnings

Tags: hard-disk, data-recovery, gpt

My system:
Intel Core i7 9750H.
Partitions are GPT type.
Root partition (ext4) is installed on SSD.
Home partition (ext4) is on Western 1TB.
Mageia 7, kernel desktop 5.4.17, KDE 5.57.
File manager `krusader`.

On `home` I have folder name `OperaDownloads` which I stored several (mostly recently) downloaded files (mostly `mhtml`) despite I don't run Opera anymore.
The `OperaDownloads` have 4 or 5 subfolders named with numbers only (such as, 49, 12, 5, ...). Most of them were created about 3 days ago, other 2 of them were created 3 months ago.

I have been running linux on Lenovo for about 1 year without problem. Do not installed any suspicious or illegal softwares.

Yesterday, when I shutdown the system, I'm sure that those subfolders were there.
About 1 hour later, right after logging in linux (I'm not sure those folders were there or already disappeared), I used `simplescreenrecorder` to record online streaming sport event (using `vivaldi` browser), that created 2 files of size 1.7 GiB on `home` folder.
After that, without rebooting, I noticed that all those subfolders were gone, other folders are intact (at least, as far as I know).

It seems that the data are lost forever because of large files created by `simplescreenrecorder`. But, the thing bugs me that I don't know the cause of this problem, which made me uneasy.

I checked memory and disk (HDD) and found no errors.

Comment: Files are not lost due to the creation of large files. Files are lost due to 1) manually deleting the files (possibly by accident), 2) running some program that "cleans up" files (possibly in particular directories that it "owns" based on age and/or file type), 3) file system corruption.

Comment: @Kusalananda I meant if the files are deleted/disappeared there're chances to recover those, but these large files may write over sectors of previous deleted files.  
About (3) how do I check for file system corruption, for GPT disks.
(1) (2) I don't delete or run such programs. And I have similar folders before without problem.